# i want sum of numbers from a list and display it in a Text widget

Tags: flutter, math, dart, sum, flutter-layout

This is my list and i want sum of unreadMsgs in Text widget. I cant figure out how can i get unreadMsgs from this list and add them. can anyone help how can i do?

```
List<UsersData> user = [

  UsersData(
    name: 'Zack Alex',
    msg: 'Im on my way.',
    status: '3 hours ago',
    dp: 'assets/Zack.jpg',
    seenMsgs: false,
    unreadMsgs: 12,
  ),

  UsersData(
    name: 'Ali sho',
    msg: 'Send an attachemnt',
    status: 'false',
    dp: 'assets/Ali.jpg',
    seenMsgs: false,
    unreadMsgs: 3
  ),

  UsersData(
    name: 'Marie',
    msg: 'Gud Morning',
    status: '23 seconds ago',
    dp: 'assets/Marie.jpg',
    seenMsgs: true,
    unreadMsgs: 6,
  ),
];
```

Comment: Please share what you've tried so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this: It works fine

```
class MyHomePage extends StatelessWidget {

  List<UsersData> user = [
    UsersData(
      name: 'Zack Alex',
      msg: 'Im on my way.',
      status: '3 hours ago',
      dp: 'assets/Zack.jpg',
      seenMsgs: false,
      unreadMsgs: 12,
    ),
    UsersData(
        name: 'Ali sho',
        msg: 'Send an attachemnt',
        status: 'false',
        dp: 'assets/Ali.jpg',
        seenMsgs: false,
        unreadMsgs: 3),
    UsersData(
      name: 'Marie',
      msg: 'Gud Morning',
      status: '23 seconds ago',
      dp: 'assets/Marie.jpg',
      seenMsgs: true,
      unreadMsgs: 6,
    ),
  ];

  // variable to hold sum of unread messages
  int sumOfUnreadMsgs = 0;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    // use a for loop to loop through your list
    for (var person in user){
      // add all the messages here
      sumOfUnreadMsgs += person.unreadMsgs ;
    }

    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
       // display sum of unread messages here
        child: Text('Sum of unread message is $sumOfUnreadMsgs'),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

OUTPUT

[image]

Comment: If number of unreadMsgs changes then i need a StatefulWidget rather than stateless.. right?

Comment: Yes, you will need a stratedul widget instead of a stateless widget @AkMahar

Answer (score 3):

### Map and Fold

The most readable way to accomplish this is to do it in two parts. First, `map` over your list of userData (aka `user`) and extract the unreadMsgs. Second, add all of the values together using `fold`.

#### Fold vs Reduce

use `fold` instead of `reduce` to provide a default value in case your `List` is ever empty.

### Example

[View it on CodePen](https://codepen.io/SupposedlySam/pen/abvqeXQ)

```
final int unreadMsgCount =
    user
      .map((data) => data.unreadMsgs)
      .fold(0, (acc, curr) => acc + curr);

return Scaffold(
  body: Center(
    child: Text(
      '$unreadMsgCount',
      style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline4,
    ),
  ),
);
```

`fold` is probably the easiest to get tripped up on. The first argument of `fold` is the `initialValue` and the second argument is a callback function defining the work you want done.

In our case we want to do addition on our unreadMsgs. By convention you'll see `acc` or `agg` as the first argument in this callback, `acc` stands for accumulator and `agg` stands for aggregation or aggregator but you can just as easily name it `prev` for previous; `curr` stands for current.

`map` takes care of extracting your `unreadMsgs` and `fold` sums those values into the `unreadMsgCount` variable we defined.

Use string interpolation to cast the `int` as a `String` for your `Text` widget.

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of operator overloading here. Probably it's not the best way but one of the possible way.

```dart
class Item {
  Item({this.id, this.msg});
  String id;
  int msg;

  Item operator +(Item other) {
    return Item(id: "", msg: (this.msg + other.msg));
  }
}

void main() {
  List<Item> data = [
    new Item(id: "A1", msg: 100),
    new Item(id: "A2", msg: 200),
    new Item(id: "A2", msg: 350)
  ];
  print(data.reduce((curr, next) => curr + next).msg);
}
```